# захват потока видео( сторонние api для python )

Tags: python, opencv

Получается я пользуюсь gige vision camera. В sdk производителя у меня идет stream, а при попытке получить поток через opencv - захвата нету. Я пользовался разными способами cv2.VideoCapture(cam), с помощью индекса камеры cam = 1 и при помощи rtsp, подобным образом cam = 'rtsp://ip_camera/numb_camera, захвата не было. Проверку isOpened() производил. Может кто может предложит вариант другой. У меня на данный момент виндоус 10 и вариантов с линукс напишите, но я пока не смогу их проверить.

Answer (score 0):

По поводу sdk непонятность так и осталась, возможно я изначально в неправильной последовательности установил что-то и у меня из-за этого возникли проблемы. Но на другом пк все заработало. А потока в opencv не было из-за того, что протокол gige vision не поддерживался в данной версии opencv, у меня стояла 4.1 примерно. В 3.4.1 все ок, либо нужно самостоятельно собирать opencv подключать работу данного протокола.